# How to add up the prices on the order page in shopware

Tags: php, smarty, shopware

I have overridden the order page in shopware and i want to create a total of all the orders that not yet been processed. i have wtitten this to just show the variables that i need. i want to add up all the totals of the invoice_amount of the orders.

```
{extends file="parent:frontend/account/orders.tpl"}

{block name="frontend_account_orders_welcome"}
    {$smarty.block.parent}
    {debug}
    <ul>
        {foreach $sOpenOrders as $sOpenOrder}
        <li> Order number :{$sOpenOrder['ordernumber']}</li>
        <li> User ID :{$sOpenOrder['userID']}</li>
        <li> Invoice_amount :{$sOpenOrder['invoice_amount']}</li>
        <li> ordertime : {$sOpenOrder['ordertime']}</li>
        <li> paymentID : {$sOpenOrder['paymentID']}</li>
        <hr>
        {/foreach}
    </ul> 
{*show here the total of the prices for the the products above something like $Total=[invoice_amount_1+invoice_amount_2]*}
{/block}
```

Any ideas on how to do that? Am a bit new to shopware and smarty

Answer (score 1):

Finally got what i wanted.

```
{extends file="parent:frontend/account/orders.tpl"}

{block name="frontend_account_orders_welcome"}
    {$smarty.block.parent}
    {$sOrderTotal = 0}
    <ul>
        {foreach $sOpenOrders as $sOpenOrder}
        <li> Order number :{$sOpenOrder['ordernumber']}</li>
        <li> User ID :{$sOpenOrder['userID']}</li>
        <li> Invoice_amount :{$sOpenOrder['invoice_amount']}</li>
        {assign var="sum_cost" value=$sum_cost+$sOpenOrder.invoice_amount}{*this is besically just declaring a variable and then adding up all the values through the loop*}
        <li> ordertime : {$sOpenOrder['ordertime']}</li>
        <li> paymentID : {$sOpenOrder['paymentID']}</li>
        <hr>
        {/foreach}
    </ul> 
<p>Total cost of all orders : {$sum_cost}</p>
{/block}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this application either, but this should work:

```
    {extends file="parent:frontend/account/orders.tpl"}

    {block name="frontend_account_orders_welcome"}
        {$smarty.block.parent}
        {debug}
        {$sOrderTotal = 0}
        <ul>
            {foreach $sOpenOrders as $sOpenOrder}
            <li> Order number :{$sOpenOrder['ordernumber']}</li>
            <li> User ID :{$sOpenOrder['userID']}</li>
            <li> Invoice_amount :{$sOpenOrder['invoice_amount']}</li>
            {$sOrderTotal += $sOpenOrder['invoice_amount']}
            <li> ordertime : {$sOpenOrder['ordertime']}</li>
            <li> paymentID : {$sOpenOrder['paymentID']}</li>
            <hr>
            {/foreach}
        </ul> 
    <p>{$sOrderTotal}</p>
    {/block}
```

I added three lines.

Comment: That just breaks it "Oops! An error has occurred!
We have been informed about the problem and try to solve it. Please try again within a short time."

Comment: Again, I'm not familiar with the smarty codebranch.  You need to set a variable equal to zero (`$sOrderTotal = 0`), and then increment it inside the loop (`$sOrderTotal += $sOpenOrder['invoice_amount']`).  The php code is correct, but how smarty handles code inside the curly brackets, I don't know.

Comment: I see what you mean and yet that is my exact issue ...  But yes I can set the variable and I can have it shown on the frontend ..  Its now the calculation that I need to figure out ...

Comment: It may be as simple as `{$sOrderTotal = $sOrderTotal + $sOpenOrder['invoice_amount']}`, doing it the old-fashioned way.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to calculate the total amount directly in php and assign it to the view. Smarty is a template engine - even when it enables you to do calculations and much more (unsafer) stuff, you should do it in php.
Instead of including the account-view, it might be the best way to write a plugin, that assigns the open orders to the view.

Comment: Thank you for your help i think i have noticed this as well and i need to do it in php because the values in the array are strings like 34,05 and yet i need to have 34.05 and its now just trimming them to 34.

Comment: You can create your custom plugin where:
1. Create your own controller `Shopware_Controllers_Frontend_MyAppAccount` with all new necessary calculation
2. or you can create some Order Listing Subscriber where you can subscribe an event `Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Account` and process your calculation.